# Event binding in JavaScript with interchangeable interfaces

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've got an application which has two interchangeable parts which require different markup and different code. By interchangeable, I mean the user can switch between the two interfaces on the fly. Currently my approach is such that when the user first loads the page, only the required markup and code is loaded. When an event signals that the interfaces need to be switched, I load the new markup via AJAX.

My question relates to the binding of events. Currently, all my events are delegated and attached to elements upstream in the DOM which I know will always be there.

Are there any consequences to this kind of event binding? Would I be better off binding/rebinding events on the fly?

Comment: From what you've described, I don't see an issue with this, but it doesn't necessarily constitute it as good practice.  That decision is up to you, unless you care to post some code and have me evaluate it.  I've been very involved in event handling lately and would be happy to be of assistance.